# How to sqoop to import oracle clob data to avro files on hdfs

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop, avro, clob

I am getting a strange error when sqooping the data from oracle DB to HDFS.
Sqoop is not able to import clob data into an avro files on hadoop.

This is the sqoop import error :

```
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: Cannot convert SQL type 2005
```

Do we need to add any extra arguments to sqoop import statement for it correctly import clob data into avro files ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Found the solution, We need to add --`map-column-java` for the `clob` columns.

For Eg: If the column name is `clob` then we have pass --`map-column-java clob=string` for `sqoop` to import the `clob` columns.